# How to render a multicolored square on an iphone using open gl es

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

Alright I'm completely new to programming and I decided to pick up the iPhone game development for dummies. I'm stuck trying to make a multi-colored square.

could someone show me how to create a subclass view using OpenGLES?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) tutorial. It has a link to a downloadable Xcode template that should contain the code you need.